# How can I style part of SVG without putting whole SVG tags in HTML?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG that looks like this

[image]

```
<svg width="589" height="911" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path class="move-line" d="m459,........... />
   <path d="m277,239c0 ......./>
</svg>
```

notice that I add `class="move-line"` on one path

then I copy the full tags above and put into my html file

add css

```
.move-line {
  stroke-dasharray: 10 10; }
```

then I got exactlly what I want like this

[image]

Now here's the problem: the whole SVG tags is too large(because of the path),

put it right into my html file makes my code very large.

**Is it possible to do something like this**

```
<img src="xxx.svg" >
```

**but still act like putting whole svg tag on html??**

I've tried

```
<object data='xxx.svg'></object>
```

and

```
<svg width=".." height=".." xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <image xlink:href="method-draw-image (1).svg">
                    </svg>
```

Both show the original svg pictrue

but my css style not working

any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: Do you really need it to be styled through your html's CSS ? Can't you just style it inside your svg document ?

Comment: What I want is make a css animate of one line.

Comment: Then you can [add css directly into your svg document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style) and reference it from wherever you want (even `<img>`)

Comment: Can't you just put your *svg* tag in a separate *php-file*, and in your HTML simply do: `<?php include 'path/to/svg.php';?>` (You'd also need to change the extension of your HTML file from *.html* to *.php*)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks you for the `<style>` tag, It works!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add external styles to the svg image by jquery just put the `<object data= "xxx.svg"></object>` then try to add styles dynamically by adding class to that using jquery.If that doesn't work then you need to put the whole code of the svg image in html page.There is no other way which works with css styles in svg.

Comment: I found that using `document.getElementById('#ObjId').contentDocument ` to get the tags of embeded Object, but only works when load html on server.

Answer (score -1):

I think css need paste inner SVG tag with special tag.